# Flex 4: Can I animate multiple objects within the same parallel?

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flex4

I have multiple spinning balls that I want to animate altogether.  Here's what I have so far but when I play the parallel (spinning.play()), nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<fx:Declarations>                       
    <fx:Vector id="kfP1" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="0" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="250" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="500" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP2" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="125" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="375" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="625" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP3" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="250" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="500" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="750" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP4" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="375" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="625" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="875" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP5" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="500" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="750" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="1000" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP6" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="625" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="875" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="1125" value="0x9F9B9B" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP7" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="125" value="0x9E9A9A" />
            <s:Keyframe time="750" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="1000" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="1125" value="0xCECCCC" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>
    <fx:Vector id="kfP8" type="spark.effects.animation.MotionPath">
        <s:MotionPath property="baseColor">
            <s:interpolator>
                <s:HSBInterpolator />
            </s:interpolator>
            <s:Keyframe time="0" value="0xFFFFFF" />
            <s:Keyframe time="125" value="0x9E9A9A" />
            <s:Keyframe time="875" value="0x9F9B9B" />
            <s:Keyframe time="1125" value="0xFFFBFB" />
        </s:MotionPath>         
    </fx:Vector>

    <s:Parallel id="spinning" repeatCount="0" duration="1125"  >
        <s:Animate id="animateP1" motionPaths="{kfP1}" target="{p1}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP2" motionPaths="{kfP2}" target="{p2}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP3" motionPaths="{kfP3}" target="{p3}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP4" motionPaths="{kfP4}" target="{p4}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP5" motionPaths="{kfP5}" target="{p5}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP6" motionPaths="{kfP6}" target="{p6}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP7" motionPaths="{kfP7}" target="{p7}"/>
        <s:Animate id="animateP8" motionPaths="{kfP8}" target="{p8}"/>
    </s:Parallel>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the format for Parallel that Catalyst produces (which works) it looks like you need to do something like this (unchecked)

```
<s:Parallel>
    <s:Parallel target = "{p1}">
        <s:Animate id="animateP1" motionPaths="{kfP1}"/>
   </s:Parallel>
    <s:Parallel target = "{p2}">
        <s:Animate id="animateP2" motionPaths="{kfP2}"/>
    </s:Parallel>
</s:Parallel>
```

It looks weird to me, but that's what the tooling produces!

Comment: I used your solution but also I realized that since I was using paths and fills that I needed to move the ids {p1} to the solidfill and not the path.  Once I did that and change the property then to "color" it worked.  Thanks!